# The IO operation at logical block address 0x1458a30a for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\00000037) was retried - Hyper-v virtual machine errors

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v

I'm encountering an issue where I have a physical server PowerEdge R740 and I have a hyper-v server where I host multiple machines, all these machines I've been seeing the errors: The IO operation at logical block address 0x1458a30a for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\00000037) was retried - Hyper-v virtual machine errors Warning 7/17/2023 3:41:12 AM disk 153 None Event ID:153 Log Name: System.

I did check the server and I haven't seen any errors pertaining the disk, nor in my physical server. Does anyone know what's the cause of this and a potential fix?